# Is there a way to 'escape' an ampersand in a C preprocessor macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a library I am porting from Windows to Linux, and I am required to make the minimal number of changes necessary.
There are some function calls in the library that I need to call variants of, with one less parameter and I am trying to use a macro to perform the substitutions.

The issue is that these calls are passing the address of a structure and I'm getting the error **"error: "&" may not appear in macro parameter list"**

For example, if the library has the following call:

```
foo(param1, &param2);
```

and I need to replace it with

```
foo_variant(&param2);
```

I am adding a conditional compile at the top of the file as follows:

```
#if defined LINUX_VARIANT
    #define  foo(param1, &param2)  foo_variant(&param2)
#endif
```

Is there any way to "escape" the ampersand to avoid this error?

If not, I did see another post that mentioned that a pointer to the struct could be defined, and use the pointer instead of taking the structure's address, but I'd like to avoid that unless there is no other option. 
Thanks ahead for any enlightenment!

Comment: Did you consider defining the macro like this: `#define  foo(param1, param2)  foo_variant(param2)`? The problematic `&` is the first one on that line.

Comment: @MagnusHoff I don't understand. If I don't add the ampersand, 1. I don't think I'll match the existing call I'm trying to substitute and 2. the replacement call won't be sending the address of the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just forward the whole argument expression:

```
#define  foo(param1, param2)  foo_variant(param2)
```

Note that, due to limitations of the preprocessor, this macro will fail if any of the arguments contains commas.

Comment: MagnusHoff suggested the same thing but I don't understand how I will match the existing call that has the ampersand in it, and how I will be sending the address of the structure if I omit the ampersand in foo_variant?

Comment: @yamex5 The preprocessor only cares about commas and parentheses. When you use `foo(&a, &b)`, the parameters of the macro are `&a` and `&b`, so `foo_variant(param2)` is correctly expanded to `foo_variant(&b)`.

Comment: @Quentinyou are correct! I tried it and the error is gone. I wouldn't have thought that the preprocessor's substitution was that sophisticated, but I'm satisfied. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Quentin's answer is correct, but to give a bit more background: the preprocessor will *textually* replace any `foo(...` with `foo_variant(...` and will also *textually* replace the parameters. If one parameter in the C source file has an ampersand, it will just see that as part of the parameter.

So the preprocessor cannot accept an ampersand in its definition, it can accept an ampersand in its expansion. With:

```
#if defined LINUX_VARIANT
    #define  foo(param1, param2)  foo_variant(&param2)
#endif
```

then

```
foo(p1, p2);
```

will be replaced by

```
foo_variant(&p2);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Paul Ogilvie. Although I did write a smaller program and compiled with the -E option to see the preprocessor output and while I *could* legally add an ampersand to the target substitution, in this case it's not what I need. But I understand, you were just giving me a better understanding of how the substitution works and what my options are.